# How to fix this function to handle different error type of error catching

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have developing mern stack web site. In that I have added below codes to handle logging.

```
 onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const obj = {
            user_name: this.state.user_name,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/login', obj)
            .then(res=> localStorage.setItem('token',(res.data.token))
                 //localstorage.setItem('username','res.data.user.username)
                 )
    }
```

When I click on login button this `onSubmit()` function called and will save token in local storage.
But, res.data have more details. (from backend it passes logged users information too)
So I want to add those to local storage. I tried that as commented in above function. It says error in res. Note : I user react for frontend.

Also I want to handle handle errors in any cases `axios.post()` didn't work as planned. In server side it send different messages for unmatched credentials and wrong passwords. How can I show those in my page. Thank you.

Comment: You should read about arrow functions, object destructuration, and Promise  methods. You have the right ideas, but I think you lack the knowledge about the syntax.

Comment: definitely I will look those concepts. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only accepted data type in `localStorage` is string, you should stringify it first using [JSON API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

```
const userDataStr = JSON.stringify(res.data);
localStorage.setItem('userData', userDataStr);
```

Now if you want to access the `userData` from `localStorage` you just need to convert it back to javascript object.

```
const userDataStr = localStorage.getItem('userData', userData);
const userData = JSON.parse(userDataStr);
```

You can have multiple `catch` in the returned promise of `axios.post`

```
axios.post()
  .catch((error) => {  })
  .catch((error) => {  })
```

But those `catch` will called with the same `error` so you need to handle it differently in each `catch`

Another suggestion:

If you want to easily handle the error, you can use higher order function like this

```
const handleError = (status, callback) => (error) => {
  if (status === error) {
    callback(error);
  }
}

axios.post()
  .catch(handleError(404, (error) => { /* only called when status === 404 */ }))
  .catch(handleError(500, (error) => { /* only called when status === 500 */ }))
```